# possible to make google chart in Extjs4 chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, javascript-framework

i wont to create this chart in extjs 4

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line

or any way to implement Google chart in extjs4

Answer (score 0):

Extjs 4  have chart library . You need to create a 
service that will return XML or json. Create store and add a store to graph.

In order to take data from yahoo (not from Google yet) I created component in C#
You can read it in my blog
http://gregnozik.blogspot.com/2011/09/yahoo-finance-api.html

After you create a store you create a chart

```
var lineChart = new Ext.chart.LineChart({   
    store: store,   
    xField: 'framework',   
    yField: 'users'  
});
```

Comment: thanks for you reply but i want to implement google chat with extjs4 any idea how to use ...?

Comment: What do you mean with extjs 4 ? Please explain exactly what do you want

Comment: i try to add google chat in extjs4 application but is not working i add google chart in Extjs3.3 so can you have any idea to add Google chart in Extjs4

Comment: Extj 4 is a set of components . To what companent you are trying to add chart ?